# SSH and identity file for jump server

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to log into `my-server` through a jump server, `jump.example.com`.

I can successfully log into the jump server without a password request:

```sh
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa user@jump.example.com
```

But if I use

```sh
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jump.example.com" user@my-server
# or
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -J user@jump.example.com user@my-server
```

I'm prompted for a password for `user@jump.example.com`.
I would not be surprised if I would prompted for a password for `user@my-server` instead.

**How can I specify an identity file for the jump server?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to add the following to your ssh config

```
Host my_server
        Hostname my-server
        ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jump_server
        User user
        IdentityFile path/to/ssh/identity/file
        Port 22
 
Host jump_server
        Hostname jump.example.com
        User user
        IdentityFile path/to/ssh/identity/file
        Port 22
```

Finally to connect to your target server use

```
ssh my_server
```

Comment: I used `ssh -F ssh_config my_server` after editing `ssh_config` locally as you suggested. I got the prompt again, but after deleting some entry in known_host, I could log into my_server.

Comment: I had to make the following change: `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jump_server` > `ProxyCommand ssh -i path/to/ssh/identity/file -W %h:%p jump_server` . The answer as it is seems not to work.

Comment: My last comment is probably only relevant for people using a non standard IdentityFile, that is other than `.ssh/id_rsa` and also othe ssh_config (using the option -F)

Answer (score 3):

A slight necro here, but I just ran into the same problem.  However in my case I was easily able to solve it looking at the original post.  In the original post, this command was tried:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jump.example.com" user@my-server
```

But it had already been indicated that the specified identity file,  ".ssh/id_rsa" was for "jump.example.com" and not "my-server".  So if you move the identity file parameter into the ProxyCommand, it should work as intended:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jump.example.com -i .ssh/id_rsa" user@my-server
```

In my specific case and testing I had a non-standard port to connect to at my "jump.example.com" server, so my command looked more like (port changed to protect the foolish):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jump.example.com -p 30000 -i .ssh/id_rsa" user@my-server
```

When I executed this command I received a prompt to type the password at "my-server".  I went just a bit further and created a different (and temporary) authorized key on my client machine for "my-server" and made it completely there without a password with this command:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@jump.example.com -p 30000 -i .ssh/id_rsa" user@my-server -i .ssh/temp_id_rsa
```

For situations where you do something often without change, going the ssh_config solution is arguably better in multiple ways.  But in my case I use ssh tunnels to pivot throughout a dynamic test environment that changes multiple times a day and I come from different locations, so a single command makes more sense.